# Alternative to Builder Pattern

Tags: java, immutability, builder, fluent

I wonder if the ff code is a viable alternative to Builder Pattern (fluent API, immutable). It works but I'm not sure of the impact to memory and performance. I am not comfortable having another class (builder).

```
class Config {

    private String x;
    private String y;

    private Config() {
    }

    public static Config create() {
        return new Config();
    }

    public String x() {
        return x;
    }

    public Config x(String x) {
        var config = new Config();
        config.x = x;
        config.y = y;
        return config;
    }

    public String y() {
        return y;
    }

    public Config y(String y) {
        var config = new Config();
        config.x = x;
        config.y = y;
        return config;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The benefits of the builder pattern are that you need only create two objects: one mutable builder object and one immutable final object; and also that the final object is created with all its fields already specified. Your pattern here is to create a new object for every field you set. If that's how you want to do it, that's fine.

Comment: You could use Telescopic Constructor, if the number of parameters is not high. If it does become high, Telescopic Constructor becomes difficult to manage, which was the original motivation for Builder Pattern. Refer the link: https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/avoid-telescoping-constructor-pattern/

Comment: @Ironluca You're right. I've read Bloch's Effective Java about telescopic constructor. I prefer fluent API and at the same time immutability which can be achieved via builder pattern. But I'm looking for an alternative to this pattern.

Comment: Thanks, @khelwood. What happens to the first objects when only the last object is assigned to a variable? Are they subject to garbage collection?

Comment: Yes any object that you don't still have a reference to is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: The nature of OOP is having more classes. If the proliferation of classes makes you uncomfortable, you should investigate alternative programming paradigms.

Comment: I see. Thanks, @khelwood.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to above, a class which is immutable, has fluent APIs ***and*** is its own builder.

```
package org.test;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class TestClass {
    
    private String x;
    private String y;
    
    HashMap<String, String> attrMap=new HashMap<>();
    private boolean initComplete=false;
    
    private TestClass() {}
    
    public static final TestClass newInstance() {return new TestClass();}
    
    public TestClass withX(String x) {attrMap.put("X", x);return this;}
    
    public TestClass withY(String y) {attrMap.put("Y", y);return this;}
    
    public void init()throws IllegalStateException{
        
        if(!initComplete) {
            
            this.x=attrMap.get("X");
            this.y=attrMap.get("Y");
            
            this.initComplete=true;
            
        }//if closing
        else throw new IllegalStateException("Already initialized ...");
        
    }//init closing

    public String getX() {return x;}

    public String getY() {return y;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        TestClass obj=TestClass.newInstance();
        obj.withX("X Value");obj.withY("Y Value");
        obj.init();
        
        System.out.println(obj.getX());
        System.out.println(obj.getY());
        
        obj.init();//Exception

    }//main closing

}//class closing
```

:D I cant think of a single reason why I would do it in production though :)

Comment: A normal builder just seems much more reasonable through. A builder can be used to force a object to be in a valid state when created. In this example we have to check initComplete to make sure all the attributes are assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a small optimization. Make a (private) no args constructor and a private all args constructor. X and y should be final. The method X and y create a new instance of Config using the all args constructor and copies all the values from the current Config instance to the new one except for the value you want to change. Very similar to your approach just that X and y can be final.

Of course this is not flawless. I think it's mandatory to document that the methods X and y return a new instance instead of returning the current one for chaining. (Without knowing the code I would expect the method to be chaining.)

Additionally if there are a lot of attributes in Config a new object will be created every time we want to change a attribute. A builder would only create one builder instance and the final object of the build process.

Lastly checking if the object is in a valid state is impossible. Yet again the builder pattern would be the better approach.